# List-Array Error?

Tags: java, arrays, string, network-programming, list

I was working on a project which required pulling down and parsing a .html page from a server, then parsing it for content. I searched a string for two values as a unit test, then saved each of them to a List, then compared them to a manually created String[]. The code is below:

SiteGrabber.java:

```
//some imports
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class SiteGrabber {

//constructor and java.net stuff

public List<String> getWords(String content){
    int prev = 0;
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tar = "<tr> <td></td><td><li>";
    int tarlen = tar.length();
    while(content.indexOf(tar, prev) != -1){
        int contentind = content.indexOf("</li>", prev);
        if(contentind != -1){
            res.add(
                content.substring(
                    content.indexOf(tar, prev) + tarlen,
                    content.indexOf("</li>", content.indexOf(tar, prev))));
            prev = contentind + 5;
        }
        else{break;}
    }
    return res;
}

}
```

SiteGrabberTest.java:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class SiteGrabberTest {

String htsTest="<tr> <td>List of scrambled words:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> <td><li>nielle</li></td> </tr><tr> <td></td><td><li>ierneb</li></td> </tr>";
//I want the text between the </td><td><li>...</li> tags.
//2 working tests that show that it sets the List.size() to 0 on a dummy string
//and that it records the right number of results in the List on a valid input.


@Test public void ValidContentTest(){
    SiteGrabber myGrabber = new SiteGrabber();
    List<String> mylst = myGrabber.getWords(htsTest);

    String[] expected = new String[] {"nielle", "ierneb"};
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong size", expected.length, mylst.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
        Assert.assertEquals("wrong word", expected[i], mylst.get(i));
                    //breaks on 1st iteration, saying it expects "nielle" and got
                    //">ierneb", implying some sort of off-by-one error.
    }


}
}
```

Comment: And the problem is....?  Please explain what your question is.  Don't make people read, compile, and run your code just to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You forgot to tell about the error itself. You know, an error/exception tells in detail about the root cause of the problem. You also know, once the root cause of the problem is understood, the solution is obvious :)

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that JUnit fails on the third test, ValidContentTest(). It returns '>ierneb' rather than nielle. I'll try to abridge some of the unneeded parts, and add JUnit error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
content.indexOf(tar, prev) + tarlen
```

to:

```
content.indexOf(tar, prev) + tarlen + 1
```

Comment: That would make sense. I initially overcompensated with tarlen - 1, and removing the - 1 helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that here...

```
content.substring(
                content.indexOf(tar, prev) + tarlen,
                content.indexOf("</li>", content.indexOf(tar, prev))));
```

You'll find your off-by-one problem... more specifically,

```
content.indexOf("</li>", content.indexOf(tar, prev))
```

... as `content.indexOf(tar, prev)` returns an index (which would range from 0 to n-1) and you're trying to use it as a length (which should range from 1 to n). 
Sound about right?

Try putting a '+1' in there...

```
content.indexOf("</li>", content.indexOf(tar, prev)+1)
```

Also, your technique won't work for all HTML documents. You should either use a proper HTML parsing library/tool or actually parse the HTML, element by element.

Comment: This was for a challenge on hackthissite.org, and the data was in a predefined format, but I see what you mean about needing a general parsing system. This is for one particular problem, rather than a framework.